# Supporting embedded PHP on a CGI app with IIS

Tags: php, iis, cgi, delphi

We have a CGI pageserver (.exe) written in Delphi running on IIS. We'd like to be able to embed PHP in these pages at some point in the near future--say, for a captcha or CMS integration--but are currently unsure how to go about this with IIS.

Using IIS, is there a way we can 'pipeline' a page through the PHP interpreter before or after passing it through our own CGI app?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to embed PHP scripting in your Delphi application, just include a system call to the PHP executable, or embed the PHP interpreter using [php4delphi](http://users.telenet.be/ws36637/php4delphi.html).

This sounds like a *really* bad idea, but you could also use a PHP script to call the Delphi CGI, strip out the returned CGI headers, `eval` the content, and reset the headers in the PHP output.  Only do this is you are **very** confident that you understand the risks of using `eval`.